# MySQL get unique list of things with multiple tag IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I have 2 tables named `tags` and `things`, both containing an `id` and a `name` column. Then, there's a third table: `thing_tags`. Which has data like this:

```
╔═══════╤═════════╗
║ tagid │ thingid ║
╟───────┼─────────╢
║     6 │       1 ║
║     6 │       2 ║
║    12 │       1 ║
║    12 │       2 ║
║    12 │       3 ║
║    15 │       4 ║
║    16 │       4 ║
║    21 │       5 ║
╚═══════╧═════════╝
```

The 2 columns have foreign key references to the `id` column of the respective tables.

What I'd like to do is to get a list of unique thing IDs that have both tag #6 and #12, so in this case, the result would be the IDs `1` and `2`, but not `3`, then find the elements with those IDs in the `things` table and retrieve them. Here's my current SQL query:

```
SELECT th.*
FROM thing_tags t
LEFT JOIN things th ON t.id = th.id
WHERE t.id IN (12,6)
ORDER BY th.name ASC
```

This does not work the way I want it to, since it also gives me the 3rd thing from the table, and returns correct results multiple times. How could I modify this query so that only those `things` will be returned that are bound to all specified `tagid`s, not just one, without having duplicate rows in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in(...)` is an `or` comparison, whereas you need an `and`. You can't change the `in` behavior, but you can add extra logic to the rest of the query to make the `in` act as if it did have `and` semantics:

```
SELECT field1, COUNT(field2) AS cnt
FROM yourtable
WHERE field2 IN (6, 12)
GROUP BY field1
HAVING cnt = 2
```

The `count()` tells you how many of the `in` field are present, and then you using the `having` clause to enforce just how many you really want to have. In your case, you only want 2, so you use `= 2`.

`having cnt > 2` would be semantically equivalent to "has AT LEAST 2".

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final attempt : :)

```
select things.* from things
inner join thing_tags a on a.thingid = things.id and a.tag_id = 6
inner join thing_tags b on b.thingid = things.id and b.tag_id = 12
```

Comment: I tried a similar solution prior to posting this question, and MySQL returned an error stating that "LIMIT & AND/OR/IN with subqueries are not supported in this version of MySQL". AFAIK I'm running the latest version.

Comment: @DJDavid98 thanks for replying. I've updated my answer with another option. Please let me know if this works

Comment: You're using `IN` with a subquery in both solutions. My MySQL server does not allow that.

Comment: I cleaned up my answer to use only inner joins, let me know if this works.

Comment: Just checked, it does work, but I still feel MarcB's solution is more correct.